# key wont turn inside

Tags: chevrolet, cobalt, ignition-key

I have a Chevy Cobalt 2008.  I drove the car yesterday before the freezing cold and during the snow. This morning the key will not turn in the ignition but the lights come on. The sun is up but still cannot turn key. The steering wheel is not locked and the car is in park completely.

Answer (score 7):

Three things I can think of:

1. Do you have another key to try? May just not like the key you are trying.
2. Is the steering wheel cocked at all, where there may be causing pressure on the key lock? Try giggling the steering column as you are trying to turn the key (assume you might have tried this, but don't know).
3. Your locking mechanism may be frozen. You could *try* heating up the ignition cylinder by using a hair dryer. If this works, shoot the ignition with just a little bit of WD-40 or some other lubricant to help it not do this again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Paulster2's suggestions, try jiggling the shifter (shaft and button).  Also, there is a recall for the ignition lock cylinder on your vehicle that has been all over the news.  The fix for that may solve your problem. Check your battery (it's in the trunk), too.  The interior lights coming on don't mean it's 100%.  There is a button in a compartment on the column behind a rubber cover.  It's for releasing a key from the ignition, but you might give it a shot.